# Python: how to write binary data to the stdout so that bash script can use process substitution?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ogg, vorbis

I need to use the program called `ogg123` for converting input ogg file to wav. My ogg is on S3 - so I need to download it first and transcode after that. But I think that will be faster to transcode sound on the fly - without writing to the disk source ogg file - using **process substitution**.

From bash I want to do this:

`ogg123 -d wav <(./test.py) -f out.wav`

In Python, for binary output, I tried:

`os.write`

`sys.stdout.buffer.write`

`fp = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb'); fp.write`

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

os.write(1, 
    s3_client.get_object(
        Bucket='my-bucket-name',
        Key='file.ogg'
    )['Body'].read()
)
```

`./test.py` in all cases print visually valid data. For example:

`xxd <(./test.py) | head` print:

```
00000000: 4f67 6753 0002 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  OggS............
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 5664 269e 011e 0176 6f72  ......Vd&....vor
00000020: 6269 7300 0000 0001 2256 0000 0000 0000  bis....."V......
00000030: 058a 0000 0000 0000 a901 4f67 6753 0000  ..........OggS..
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000050: 5096 ab47 0e16 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  P..G............
00000060: ffff c503 766f 7262 6973 0600 0000 6666  ....vorbis....ff
00000070: 6d70 6567 0000 0000 0105 766f 7262 6973  mpeg......vorbis
00000080: 2242 4356 0100 4000 0018 4210 2a05 ad63  "BCV..@...B.*..c
00000090: 8e3a c815 218c 19a2 a042 ca29 c71d 42d0  .:..!....B.)..B.
```

But all these variants generates the same error from ogg123:

`Error opening /dev/fd/63 using the oggvorbis module.  The file may be corrupted.`

I tried the same file locally - file is correct:

```
$ ogg123 -d wav file.ogg -f out.wav

Audio Device:   WAV file output

Playing: file.ogg
Ogg Vorbis stream: 1 channel, 22050 Hz

Done.
```

What can you recommend?

Comment: Are you sure that `ogg123` can read from a stream (that is, a non-seekable input source)?

Comment: I am not sure...

Comment: You could try [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to see if it was an issue in ogg123.  Also, `diff --binary <(./test.py) file.ogg` to check for a bit-for-bit match.

Comment: @larsks [ogg123](https://github.com/xiph/vorbis-tools/blob/master/ogg123/oggvorbis_format.c#L340) does specify a seek callback.  The [underlying library](https://github.com/xiph/vorbis/blob/master/lib/vorbisfile.c#L878) does have some checks for seekable, but `ogg123` doesn't seem to report detailed result codes.  Vitaly, I think you may need to step through `ogg123` with a debugger to see exactly where the error is.  **Edit** [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63933/63804) suggests using a named pipe instead of process substitution - maybe try that?  Probably no different, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for help, I found that I can fetch through S3 using pure ogg123:

```
ogg123 -d wav https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/file.ogg -f out.wav
```